# Visa for transit in the US

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, transit, indonesian-citizens

I'm planning to go to Mexico and all flights from Amsterdam will have a layover in the US. For the layover, do I need a US visa just for this transit?

I hold an Indonesian Passport and a Dutch residence permit!

thanks,